# field disppearing on lwc record form during edit

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

We have an LWC component that shows details of an Order. We are using lightning-record-form to show order fields to be able to edit if required.
We can see the fields with inline edit icon next to them when page is loaded, but when clicked on edit all fields disappear and only Cancel and Save buttons are displayed on page.

**Note:** This was working fine till now and suddenly there is this weird behavior. No changes have been done to this component recently.

images for reference below

Component in Order detail page tab
[image: Component on Order]

Edit behaviour
[image: Edit behaviour]

Comment: The component honors field level security. Make sure that the user you're logged in as has Edit permission for each of those fields.

Comment: Yes, but even with admin it doesn't work. I suspect this is related to latest SF releases/critical updates.

Comment: I'm facing the same exact problem. I suppose that is a release problem but I found nothing in the "Known Issue" section

Answer (score 0):

> This could be due to critical updates applied to the org that might
>   affect the behavior you are seeing.

You can track it here.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001GqH9QAK&title=lightning-record-form-performance-regression-introduced-in-spring-20.
Check if you org is updated patch 11 fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem for about 2-3 days on all sandoxex, after which the anomaly no longer occurred. We opened a Support Case to Salesforce and he told us that the anomaly was probably resolved with the release of the Spring '20 Patch 11. Now the component work properly on all sandboxes.